# asyncio event_loop in a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6, python-asyncio, event-loop

What is the best method to have an asyncio event loop run in a Flask app?

My main.py looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
    except:
        logging.critical('server: CRASHED: Got exception on main handler')
        logging.critical(traceback.format_exc())
        raise
```

To add the option of async tasks, I needed to create an `event_loop` before running the `app`, but even when stopping the app run, a background thread still hangs (observable in debugger)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
    except:
        logging.critical('server: CRASHED: Got exception on main handler')
        logging.critical(traceback.format_exc())
        raise
    finally:
        app.event_loop.stop()
        app.event_loop.run_until_complete(app.event_loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        app.event_loop.close()
```

And using the following to create async tasks:

```
def future_callback(fut):
    if fut.exception():
        logging.error(fut.exception())

def fire_and_forget(func, *args, **kwargs):
    if callable(func):
        future = app.event_loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args, **kwargs)
        future.add_done_callback(future_callback)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Task must be a callable')
```

The only solution I could find was to add `exit()` at the end of the `finally` block, but I don't think its the correct solution.

Comment: The best is not to call asyncio code from Flask, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the best solution I found was to host my Flask app in `uwsgi` which enables to use `mules` and `spooler` for async tasks

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Spooler.html

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Mules.html

Answer (score 2):

I initially took the approach of 1 event_loop for the entire flask app, but didn't like that for a few different reasons.

Instead, I created a helper file, `custom_flask_async.py` with 2 functions in,

```
import asyncio


def get_set_event_loop():
    try:
        return asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if e.args[0].startswith('There is no current event loop'):
            asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
            return asyncio.get_event_loop()
        raise e


def run_until_complete(tasks):
    return get_set_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

I only check for and `get_set` the event_loop if it's going to be used, and waited upon in a particular request.  And because the main way I'm using this is with a `run_until_complete` with a gather, I've that in the helper too.

I'm also not sure if this is the best approach, or what drawbacks there are to this method, but it definitely works for my purpose.

Comment: With Python 3.7 you can use asyncio.run right? That would create the event loop and close it at a request level